# How to keep your terminal running when laptop lid is closed

Tags: gnome-terminal

This my first time using Ask Ubuntu so something might go wrong

I am running Ubuntu 13.10 on a laptop. I'm making a server (Not a Ubuntu server) and I need to 24/7, I normally have my laptop charging and the lid closed. I just need to find out how to let my Ubuntu terminal running even if my lid is closed, and when its not charged.

Regards, Tom

Comment: When you say "lid is closed" you mean on suspencion or hibernation?

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu. Check the Power Management application, there should be an option to "do nothing" when the lid is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have 2 ways to do it:

1. you can use one of the real terminal in front end by type ctrl+alt+F1
2. you can deactivate the action on lid close on power setting. this will allow your laptop to run even the lid is closed